# android how to scroll to see all the widget of the view

Tags: android, android-widget

In one of my androids activities, I have several widget in a vertical linearlayout. The length of this layout is bigger than the screen and thus I cannot see the widget at the bottom.
In the Emulator, is there a special scroller to implement or a particular action to do to be able to scroll up and down ?
Thanks a lot,
Luc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want to wrap your `LinearLayout` in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: @Luc Not at all. This should have been the default for all activities!